If $f=\Theta(g)$, does $h(f) = \Theta(h(g))$?
I am wonderimg whether or not the following statement is true: if $f=\Theta(g)$, then $h \circ f = \Theta(h \circ g)$ where $f,g,h$ are any functions mapping from the positive reals to the positive reals, and $$f = \Theta(g) \iff \exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists k \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{+} x>x_0 \implies c\cdot g(x) \le f(x) \le k \cdot g(x)$$.  The reason why I ask is because a worksheet's answer solutions I was looking at seemed to use this fact; yet it seemed intuitively false to me. I thought of the example $f(x) = x$,$g(x) = 100+x$, and $h(x) = \lfloor\frac x {100} \rfloor$, but couldn't formally prove that this was a counterexample. I would appreciate it if somebody could prove this statement either true or false. Also, if somebody provides a counterexample, I would strongly prefer that $f,g,h$ are monotonic increasing.

What are you using $\Theta$ to represent? and by $h(f)$ do you mean $h \circ f$ ?

That's false. For example, consider $f(n)=n^2$, $g(n)=n^2-n$, and $h(n)=e^n$ (note they are all positive and increasing on $[2,\infty)$).
Trivially, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=1$, so $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent, hence $f=\Theta(g)$.
But $\frac{h\circ f(n)}{h\circ g(n)}=e^n$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{h\circ f(n)}{h\circ g(n)}=\infty$. As a consequence, $h\circ f\neq O(h\circ g)$ hence $h\circ f\neq \Theta(h\circ g)$.
